# How can I plot from a maximum range to a minimum range in Python

Tags: python, numpy, plot, histogram

I have some troubles trying to plot a figure in python for a homework I had in university. I want to plot a figure from the maxim range to the minimum range in the x-axis. My code is the next one:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function that plots the cummulative histogram
def plotFunction( array , numberBins ):

    # Array of elements that will be plotted on log scale
    elements = array

    # evaluate the histogram
    values, base = np.histogram(elements, bins= len( numberBins ) )
    #evaluate the cumulative
    cumulative = np.cumsum(values)
    # plot the cumulative function
    plt.plot(  cumulative , base[:-1] , c='blue')


    plt.show()
```

I would like to set the axis the other way around, from 200 to 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the xlim function or the set_xlim method of the axes:

```
plt.xlim(200, 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to manually set the limits, as @tillsten mentioned.  This is the simple, straight-forward way, and if you're just making a static figure, it's what you want.

You can even do `plt.xlim(plt.xlim()[::-1])` to avoid having to enter specific ranges.

However, this turns autoscaling off as a side-effect. If you're going to be adding more to the plot (perhaps interactively), you may want to use `ax.invert_xaxis()` instead.

In your case, you're calling the plot methods through `pyplot` (instead of as methods of the axes), so you'll need to grab the axes instance first.  E.g.

```
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
```